# Applying class to dynamic element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

Iam creating a dynamic input and applying a class to it, but its not working.
My class:

```
$(".numeric_input").keypress(function(e) {
    var a = [];
    var k = e.which;
    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
       a.push(i);
    if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

My code:

```
var table = document.getElementById('sizeTable');
for(var i=0;i<sizes.length;i++) {
    $("<td></td>").html('<input type=text class=numeric_input name=rows['+i+'].quantity>').appendTo(tr);
    $(tr).appendTo(table);
}
```

The same class applied to other elements are working fine. Any help

Comment: Is the class not applied or does the event handler not work? I see `class=numeric_input` in your code, so I don't see a reason why the element should not have that class.

Comment: The class is applied, I can see via inspectElement but event handler is not working. It is accepting all values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation (*as your `.numeric_input` being added dynamically*)

```
$(document).on('keypress',".numeric_input",function(e) {
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 3):

Because you are creating `.numeric_input` dynamically, you need to target the event differently.  Instead of `.keypress()` use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.numeric_input', function (e) {
    var a = [];
    var k = e.which;
    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
       a.push(i);
    if (!(a.indexOf(k) >= 0))
       e.preventDefault();
});
```